# LC-3 Subroutine Access Violation

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am learning subroutines but I am getting an access violation error. My subroutine is supposed to count the number of characters the userinputted and ending the program with newline (does not count newline).

```
.ORIG x3000
    LEA R1, user_string         ;R1 - the starting address the character array
    LD R6, top_stack_addr    ;R6 - the address of Subroutine: SUB_GET_STRING
    LD R6,SUB_GET_STRING_PTR            
    JSR SUB_GET_STRING_PTR

HALT

;--------------
;local data
;--------------
user_string          .BLKW #100
SUB_GET_STRING_PTR .FILL x3400

;--------------
;subroutine address
;--------------
top_stack_addr  .FILL xFE00
.END


.ORIG x3400
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Subroutine: SUB_GET_STRING
; Parameter (R1): The starting address of the character array
; Postcondition: The subroutine has prompted the user to input a string,
;               terminated by the [ENTER] key (the "sentinel"), and has stored
;               the received characters in an array of characters starting at (R1).
;               the array is NULL-terminated; the sentinel character is NOT stored.
; Return Value (R5): The number of non-sentinel characters read from the user.
;                    R1 contains the starting address of the array unchanged.
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Backup all used registers, R7 first, using proper stack discipline
SUB_GET_STRING_3400

    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R7, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R5, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R4, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R3, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R2, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    STR R1, R6, #0
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
    LEA R0, user_prompt
    PUTS
                    
    LD R6, Hex_0A
    NOT R6, R6
    ADD R6, R6, #1              ;R6 = -12 (NEWLINE)
    AND R5, R5, #0              ;set r5 = 0, r5 is used to count the input string length
                    
    INPUT_LOOP
        GETC
        OUT
        ADD R3, R0, #0          ;R3 = R0
        ADD R3, R3, R6          ;R3 = R3+R6
        BRnp #2             ;if input is newline, end the loop
        STR R3, R1, #0      ;store 0. (string is end with 0)
        BR Input_Stop 
        STR R0, R1, #0          ;store input in the user_string block
        ADD R1, R1, #1          ;move the pointer to the next address
        ADD R5, R5, #1          ; R5 += 1
        BR INPUT_LOOP
    Input_Stop
;restore            
    LDR R1, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1
    LDR R2, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1
    LDR R3, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1
    LDR R4, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1
    LDR R5, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1
    LDR R7, R6, #0
    ADD R6, R6, #1

;--------------------------------------------------------------------
RET
      
;local data
user_prompt         .STRINGZ "Enter the string: \n"
Hex_0A              .FILL x0A       ;newline
.END
```

This is the error I am getting:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSwt3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSwt3.png)
The access violation pops up when the program reaches BRnzp TRAP_HALT. I'm not sure what this means.

The program works with the old way of backing up and restoring using ST and LD.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ORIG x3000
    LEA R1, user_string         ;R1 - the starting address the character array
    LD R6, top_stack_addr    ;R6 - the address of Subroutine: SUB_GET_STRING
    LD R6,SUB_GET_STRING_PTR            
    JSR SUB_GET_STRING_PTR

HALT
```

In the above code sequence, it sets up the stack pointer `R6`, to refer to `xFE00` — appropriate free memory.  However, then immediately modifies the stack pointer to refer to `x3400`, which is where the code is.

Since subsequent code does indeed use the stack pointer, to save values, and the stack pointer, `R6`, is pointing to the code, the code is in effect overwriting itself.  (The results are predictable, but hard to reason exactly what will happen without detailed analysis of what code is overwritten when and with what.)

I wouldn't bother debugging further without fixing this error.

---

Suggest applying debugging techniques: single step the program and between each line, verify that the appropriate action was taken.

If you do that with this code, for example, you would immediately have seen the value in R6 going bad, which should have stopped you there.  If you didn't notice that, then in the next few instructions, the stack pushes are going to the wrong location, which also could have been verified using single step debugging.

Debugging skills are absolutely necessary in any programming endeavor, so this is a great opportunity to develop yours along side learning LC-3.

Comment: Ok, I believe the reason why I was getting access violation was because I was using R6 inside my subroutine/code which isn't allowed.